# Returning multiple nodes when searching a tree/trie?

Tags: c#, tree, suffix-tree

I have constructed a suffix trie, a tree containing all the suffixes of a string, where each node contains only one character, with a SuffixNode at the end of each path which contains the locations of the suffixes within the string.

Let's say my trie contains the words, "Cat", "Car" and "Can" and I want to search for "Ca", the result should return 3 suffix nodes since the search string is found in 3 different places. I managed to search the tree for "Ca", but once I reach that point, I don't know how to continue traversing the children of the 'a' node to find all the suffix nodes.

I was thinking of using some sort of collection to add the suffix nodes to and then return the collection. Does this approach make sense, or are there better solutions?

I have solved the searching problem below. The reason it wasn't returning any nodes has to do with the creation of the tree and the differences between nodes:

```
public void SearchTrie(Node parent, String s, List<SuffixNode> suffixes)
    {
        Node n = FindNode(parent, s);
        FindSuffixes(n, suffixes);
    }

    private void FindSuffixes(Node parent,List<SuffixNode> suffixes)
    {            
        if (parent is SuffixNode)
        {
            suffixes.Add((SuffixNode)parent);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<char, Node> child in parent.children)
            {
                FindSuffixes(child.Value, suffixes);
            }
        }
    }

    private Node FindNode(Node parent, String s)
    {
        if ((s.Length == 1) && parent.children.ContainsKey(s[0]))
        {
            Node n = parent.children[s[0]];
            return n;
        }

        while (s[0].ToString() != "")
        {
            if (parent.children.ContainsKey(s[0]))
            {
                if ((s.Length > 1))
                {
                    return FindNode(parent.children[s[0]], s.Substring(1));
                }

            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Node:

```
class Node
{
    public char label;
    public Node parent;
    public Dictionary<char,Node> children;

    public Node(Node NewParent, char NewLabel)
    {
        this.parent = NewParent;
        this.label = NewLabel;
        children=new Dictionary<char,Node>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post some code/examples ? It could help to understand the question... because IMO you should simply traverse the subtree (below "CA")...

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I'm finding it a bit difficult. I'll post my previous search function, which other code would be useful?

Comment: can you post also the Node class ?

Comment: I updated my question with my new search method and the node class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was thinking of using some sort of collection to add the suffix nodes to and then return the collection.

That would be the first choice.

> ..., or are there better solutions?

There are other solutions, like

- filling a list supplied by the caller
- use an iterator block with `yield return`

But w/o any special requirements, fill a `List<string>` and return it as `IEnumerable<string>`.